# Live view from kinect on android phone

Tags: android, streaming, kinect, live, openni

I have a computer connected to kinect. I'd like to view the live video stream from kinect on an android phone via Bluetooth or WiFi connection.

Would openni solve this problem? Are there alternative solutions other than those using streaming servers ( like red5).

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed an app which streams the Kinect preview (both color and depth) at 30FPS. Here are the details of the implementation.

**Hardware:** Connect the Kinect sensor to **rooted** Android device (Nexus 6) using OTG cable. The green LED on the OTG must glow. If the LED does not glow then it means that your android device does not support USB OTG mode.

**Software:** I have used OpenCV4Andoid, libusb and libfreenect.

**Sourcecode:** https://github.com/jaiprakashgogi/AndroidKinectPreview

The steps involved are as follows:

1. Install the apk to Android device
2. Connect the Kinect sensor using OTG cable.
3. Login to the linux adb shell using "ADB wireless" app (devices needs
   to be rooted)

Type the following command on the Android ADB shell. Voila :).

```
$ su
$ chmod -R 777 /dev/bus/usb/*
```

Click the button to start preview at 30fps.